# How to add static imports to IntelliJ IDEA live template

Tags: java, intellij-idea, live-templates

I need to port the following Eclipse template to IntelliJ IDEA

```
/**
 * See method name.
 */
@${testType:newType(org.junit.Test)}
public void should${testdesc}() {
  // given ${cursor}
  ${staticImport:importStatic('org.hamcrest.Matchers.*', 'org.junit.Assert.*', 'org.mockito.BDDMockito.*')} 
  // when

  // then

}
```

What I've got so far is

```
/** 
 * See method name.
 */
@org.junit.Test
public void should$EXPR$() { 
  // given $END$ 
  ${staticImport:importStatic('org.hamcrest.Matchers.*', 'org.junit.Assert.*', 'org.mockito.BDDMockito.*')} 
  // when 

  // then

}
```

And then tick the `Shorten FQ names` flag.

What's the IDEA equivalent for the `${staticImport:importStatic()}` expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot just import the static imports in a live template. (You can for a file template, see below). But you can when using a method in the template. You just simply fully qualify the class and then select both the "Shorten FQ names" and "Use static import if possible" options. For example, the following:

```
org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("$END$", $EXPECTED$, $ACTUAL$);
```

Will result in:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
. . .
assertEquals("my error message", myExpectedVar, myActualVar);
```

when invoked. (I have the `$EXPECTED$` and `$ACTUAL$` variables set to `variableOfType("")` with corresponding default values `expected` and `actual`)

If you want certain static imports to be included in all your unit tests, then I would recommend editing the "Class" *File and Code Template*. For example:

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

#if ($NAME.endsWith("Test"))
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;
#end

#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} 
{  

#if ($NAME.endsWith("Test"))
    // Add any default test methods or such you want here.
#end

}
```

Keep in mind however, the static import will immediately be removed if you have the "Optimize imports on the fly" option (in IDE Settings > Editor > Auto import) turned on, unless you also include a method (or other code) that makes use of the static import.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted when I Googled for "assertEquals live template", and it is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Now its possible to add **live templates** with **static imports**:

> You have to check static import in Options

```java
@org.junit.Test
public void should$EXPR$when$CONDITION$() {
    org.junit.Assert.assertThat(null, org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is(org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue())); 
}
```

[image]